# Как наполнить элемент результатом поиска без обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

## Помогите решить задачку:

Есть блок  состоящий из:

1. search form + button
2. Либо приглашение ввести запрос, либо N результатов запроса ( в дальнейшем планирую использовать пагинацию в случае большого числа результатов )
   Как сделать, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку этот блок наполнялся элементами? Пока что нагуглил только до Ajax, но все найденные примеры делают живой поиск и взаимодействуют с php

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но каждый раз пытаясь добавить слово "здравствуйте", при исправление вопроса - слово удаляется) Поздороваюсь здесь. Приветствую)

Comment: а каков алгоритм поиска? что и где ищется?

Comment: Будут искать карточки Mongo имеющие подстроку в каком-то из полей. Пока что для примера буду генерировать схожие сущности. Бэк на python